# How to set counter to count number of view on each post

Tags: reactjs, redux, counter

I sat a counter which is counting the total number of visit on my post instead of counting the views on per post. here is the code below:

```
const ViewPost=()=>{
    const [user,setUser] = useState({
        title:"",
        body:"",
        date:""
     });
     const {id} = useParams();
     const [count,setCount]=useState(parseInt(localStorage.getItem('count')));
     
     console.log(count)
     
     useEffect(()=>{
         loadUser();

     },[])
     
     const IncNum=()=>{
       setCount(count+1);
    }
    localStorage.setItem('count',count)
     const loadUser = async  ()=>{
        const result = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3004/posts/${id}`,IncNum());
        setUser(result.data);
       // console.log(result.data)
    } ;
    
    return(
        <div>
        <span> {(user.title) ==='' ?<ErrorPage /> :
        
        <div className="container py-4">
        <Link className="btn btn-primary" to= "/blog"> Back to home</Link>
        <h1 className="display-4"> Post: {id}</h1>
        <hr/>
        <ul className="list-group w-100">
        <li className="list-group-item"> Title:{user.title}</li>
        <li className="list-group-item"> Body:{renderHtml(user.body)}</li>
        <li className="list-group-item"> Date:{user.date}</li>
       
        </ul>
        <h1> {/*count*/} </h1>
        
        </div>

    
    }</span>
        
     
        
        </div>
      
     
    )
}
export default ViewPost;
```

Comment: Can anyone help me out of this @shubhamkhatri